# F# CSV - for each row create an array from columns data

Tags: arrays, csv, f#

I have a CSV file, where the fst column is a title and next 700+ columns are some int data.

```
Title D1 D2 D3 D4 .. D700
Name1  0  1  7  5     48
```

I try to use CsvProvider to read the file and then convert data to my custom type

```
type DigitRecord = { Title:string; Digits:int[] }
```

The problem is I don't know how to put all column data (except the first one with a title) into a int[] array.

```
 let dataRecords = 
    CSV.Rows 
    |> Seq.map (fun record -> {Title = record.Title; Digits = ???})
```

I want to get a record with Title=Name1 and Digits=[|0,1,7,5...48|]

I'm newbie in F#, I'd be grateful for any help!

Comment: are you sure that the best option here is to use csvTypeProvider?

Comment: Nope. However I'm doing some research than just technically trying to solve the problem :) If there is a way to do such transformations with TypeProviders - I'd like to get to know it.

Comment: For example, there is one..classic? solution to use System.IO, read lines of the file and then split it. 

File.ReadAllLines(path).[1..] |> Array.map (fun row -> row.Split(','))

Something like that, I suppose. If someone need any solution to handle this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171831/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-ayto-maximo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use [`CsvParser`](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvFile.html) like this:

```
let readData (path : string) seps =
    CsvFile.Load(path, seps).Rows
    |> Seq.map
        (fun row -> row.Columns.[0], row.Columns |> Array.skip 1 |> Array.map int)
    |> Seq.map
        (fun (title, digits) -> {Title = title; Digits = digits})
```